# Google Glass ADB devices doesn't find. OMAP4430 driver not installed (can't find it!)

Tags: android, google-glass

Plugging in Glass via USB allows me to browse files and such. But even with debug mode ON I can't get it to show up with the `adb devices` command. Also my Windows system said it couldn't find an OMAP4430 device driver (which is the Glass SoC I believe).

What do?

Comment: Ditch your friends macbook, I included an answer below that shows how to get this to work on your windows machine.  Please comment if it works for you!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This was pretty frustrating, but I got this to work on Windows 7 with these steps, which are similar to what Jenny Murphy described except this actually works and has the right file names etc:

1 - Find your usb driver folder within the adt bundle folder, on my computer it was here:

> C:\Users\mscheel\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver

2 - Open up the file called android_winusb.inf

Add this magical snippet to both the [Google.NTamd64] and [Google.NTx86] section, which includes the correct PID and VID for Google Glass (Updated May 2014 after helping a student at Boston AnDevCon):

;Google Glass
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0d02
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_0d02

[Update August 2013 - In windows you can find the values for the above by going into Device Manager, right clicking your device > Properties > Details Tab > Change Dropdown to Hardware Ids.  Once you have them make sure they match what you put into your inf file, for a developer I helped recently we had to comment out the top two lines above and just use the last two lines]

3 - Go into Device Manager and find the yellow warning icon for Glass, right click it and select Update Driver Software, choose select from computer and enter in the path in step #1 (just the parent folder of android_winusb.inf).  My computer gave an anti-virus warning that I dismissed, and shortly after I was able to use [Droid AT Screen](http://droid-at-screen.ribomation.com/installation/) to mirror my Glass display onto my windows PC, which is great for presentations.

The sweet taste of success:

[image]

Note that after this Glass will display in Device Manager as "Android Phone > Android Composite ADB Interface".

[image]

Another addition, May 2014, from helping a user: Sometimes Windows will cheerfully tell you that 
your drivers are already up to date and you are using the correct ones.  Even though you made modifications to the inf file.  "The best driver software for your device is already installed”.  If this happens look for the bottom option during the workflow “Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer”.  Its not easy to spot and seems like the same choice you are making, but keep an eye out for it.  This will help force Windows to start using your changes.

Comment: In helping another developer out I had to do a slight modification of the steps above, I will update the answer.

Comment: I had to use CompositeAdbInterface instead of Single for my V2 devices, like so: %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216

Comment: For my XE-C I used the following:   

``%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216&MI_01``  
``%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01``

Comment: In step 3, i got "Windows found driver software for your device but encountered an error while attempting to install it" "The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering." *cough*

Comment: XE12/new hardware update (I'm the poster).  Try this: device manager, portable devices, Glass 1, right click, uninstall, with the device plugged in this triggered a reinstall of usb drivers and now glass shows under portable devices, it showed momentarily in other devices, but no longer does, it also no longer shows under Android Phone.  It does show up after a $adb devices command and in DDMS / Eclipse.  I'm a little embarrassed to admit this took me 2 hours to get working (XE12,Win7, new hardware, prev. working on pre-exchange hardware) :(

Comment: Worked for me. This saved me a lot of time. Only thing I had to differently/additionally was to check the box to delete the driver software when uninstalling the glass, and then re-install the driver.  Otherwise, it didn't seem to have any effect. Thanks.

Comment: This got me most of the way there, then I had to: Device Manager > This PC > Android Device > "Android ADB..." > "Update Driver Software..." > Browse My Computer > "Let me pick..." (there were 3 options) > "USB Composite Device".  Make sure Glass is running the latest firmware.

Comment: 1500$ and I have to manually edit config file to make it work.... wow, really impressive! Anyway, following the above steps worked like a charm for me after wasting half a day struggling...

Answer (score 8):

***Windows 8*** users will need to follow the directions @ http://tivadj-tech.blogspot.com/2012/09/certificate-check-error-when-installing.html to get the driver to install . This step must be completed before you start installing the driver!

---

Summary of steps at link above (print or make a note of these steps before proceeding)

- get to **PC Settings** screen, select left menu item **General**, scroll right pane if needed and select **Advanced startup** button.  You will advance to a new screen.
- select **Troubleshooting**, then **Advanced Options**, then **Startup Settings**, **Restart**.  Your system will reboot but pause with a menu of choices.
- choose **Disable driver signature enforcement** (should be item 7).  Your system will continue with the boot.
- install driver following steps in accepted answer above.

Comment: When I updated from Windows 8 to 8.1 I eventually noticed the driver was removed or disabled.  Installing the driver again worked... again.

Comment: well eventually Google Glass will go to prod and we shouldnt have to deal with this hack.

Answer (score 5):

I experienced a slightly different problem this morning which made me back track on all of the above still without success.

I could see Glass as the correct type in Android device manager but still had nothing in adb - devices, or Eclipse of course.

The solution I found was to uninstall the Android Composite ADB Interface under Android Device within the Windows Device Manager.  DO NOT CHECK the box that says delete the device driver software or you'll need to reload that again also.  Then I removed the USB cable from the computer.  Reconnected again and all was well.  You might need a reboot before reconnecting the cable but I didn't.

One clue to this was that when you connect via USB normally you get the popup asking what you want to do, import pictures, open windows explorer etc.  I was not getting this which was my clue to something being wrong.

Once it works you should also see Glass as a device in your 'computer' similar to how you would see a USB Drive.  This was missing for me originally also.

One interesting piece was that I did have this working previously on the exact same computer.  Initially I thought this was down to something related to the XE12 update, rather than a magical mystery of Windows 7 Pro 64but USB drivers.

Comment: This just worked for me.  I've had the accepted answer work on a couple of other pairs though.  Very weird.

Comment: My case is similar but slightly different.  In my case, I needed to delete the driver software during uninstalling.  Then, next time, I connected the Glass to PC, it recognizes it as a Composite ADB Device and also "Glass 1" dialog is popped up too.  After that, adb correctly recognizes my Glass. :0

Answer (score 2):

**Fastboot**

`%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0451&PID_D022`
`%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0451&PID_D022&REV_0100`

The fastboot interface shows up under VID_0451&PID_D022.

Comment: I think you meant %CompositeAdbInterface% for the second entry - also a reminder to get the VID and PID values directly from the device entry in Device Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Poking around I found a [blog entry](http://thisisignite.com/android-development-on-toshiba-at200-with-omap4430/) that seems to have a fix. Here's a copy and paste of [Michal's](http://thisisignite.com/author/michal/) tutorial:

...[F]or half of the day the ADB didn’t want to hear about the new tablet that it supposed to cooperate with.

Here is how you can force it to listen:

1. Downloading Android SDK is necessary. Also, we will need additional android USB drivers that can be installed through the SDK manager.
2. After installing the Android SDK, go to `../sdk/extras/google/usb_driver`. We will modify the android_winusb.ini file a little bit. Edit the file and find `[Google.NTx86]` or `[Google.NTamd64]` lines. Paste provided code right below those two lines. Don’t modify anything else.

   ```
   ; OMAP-3/4
    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D101
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D102&MI_01
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D106&MI_02
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D107&MI_03
    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_FFFFE
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_FFFE&MI_01
    %SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D022
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D022&MI_01
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D10A&MI_01

   ; OMAP-3 / 4 - ICS
    %CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_0930&PID_D109&MI_01
   ```
3. The next step requires modifications in android_usb file that can be found in `“%USERPROFILE%\.android\`. By `%USERPROFILE%` O mean the Documents and Settings folder of your current logged user. The .android folder won’t be visible so you have to enable the visibility of hidden files.
4. Edit android_usb to change vendor ID to match your device’s vendor. The ID I used is 0930 which matches Tochiba vendor ID listed on Android’s official web site.  If you’re trying to enable your OMAP4 Android device  and it is not Tochiba, then just modify 0930 in both edited files to match your gadget. You can get the vendor ID’s from [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).
5. When you connect the tablet via USB, Windows will try to look for appropriate drivers and install them. And no suprise, it will fail.  Go to ‘Device Manager’ in Windows and you should see yellow ‘?’ sign for an unknown device. Click on it and install or update the driver. Choose driver manualy from your hard drive and navigate to  the android_winusb.ini file that you modified before. Ignore warnings and install the driver.
6. Navigate with the `cmd` to `../sdk/platform-tools/` and use `adb kill-server` command. It will kill the ADB server.
7. You can connect your tablet via the USB cable. To check if ADB sees the tablet, type ‘adb devices’. As an output you should get the ID of your device and from now on Eclipse should be able to detect it.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will give this a try and report back.

Comment: Hey, step 4 is a little confusing - the closest file I have to "android_usb" is "adb_usb.ini" and it's empty, so I'm unsure what to change - do I just paste the ID number? Also, that file has a comment that says DO NOT EDIT (use 'android update adb')

Comment: This may be an issue with your ADB installation. Have you tried using ADB from another system? This would help isolate or rule that our as a cause.

Comment: Everything's working fine on my friend's MacBook Air. I literally downloaded the SDK, plugged in Glass, ran `adb devices` and it shows up.

Comment: I am also unable to see glass in adb. It's because windows does not install the usb drivers... even if I point it to extras/google/usb_driver. I recall having the same issue with a nexus 10. android_winusb.ini is named android_winusb.inf on my 64 bit windows 7 computer... not sure if that matters?

Comment: @aleph_null exact same issue here (even the naming). I decided screw it, gonna use my friend's Mac for now.

Comment: @YoungMoney - The easiest way to hit me up is on Google+: google.com/+JennyMurphy

Comment: These instructions have the wrong file name in step 2, and the wrong content to put into that file, also the step 4 that helped that user with a tablet is not necessary for Glass.  I added an answer below that I tested on a Windows 7 machine, that corrects these items.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your android_winusb.inf file under the section [Google.NTamd64]

```
;Google Glass
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%SingleAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
%CompositeAdbInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216
```

Update the driver in device manager.
Confirmed working on XE7.