# DDMS and android studio Unable to see google glass

Tags: adb, google-glass, ddms

I am new to google glass and trying to set google glass with eclipse and android studio to get start developing with it but despite my all efforts I am unable to see it. I have ran all the instructions mentioned on glass page and tried all the solutions like these. 
[DDMS unable to see Google Glass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390624/ddms-unable-to-see-google-glass/20412429#20412429)
[Google Glass ADB devices doesn't find. OMAP4430 driver not installed (can't find it!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928983/google-glass-adb-devices-doesnt-find-omap4430-driver-not-installed-cant-find)

Now I have installed all the drivers and did what these solutions suggested but no help.
[image]
then I connected my phone and it is showing in `adb devices` command in command prompt but not the glass. Please help me with this as this .... Any help would be highly appreciated !
And I am running it on windows 7 64 bit.

Comment: *"Unable to see my google glass"* - I'm tempted to make an obscure joke about needing to wear your glasses to find your glasses being a bootstrapping problem.  But I will resist.  :-)

Comment: @StephenC well I am not very good in english so you can expect mistakes ;-)

Comment: Having reread your Question, it seems that the problem is really about configuring devices, etc.  It would be more appropriate to ask that on superuser.com.

Comment: @StephenC Ok i will ask it there .but I have tried to configure exactly how the documentation has told to do it but no help..

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435778/google-glass-is-not-listed-as-android-device-by-adb

Comment: @Rems I already tried that but no help and by the way that questions is for windows 8 and I am using windows 7. And you can see my mobile is being listed but not the glass and I have implemented every method but no help ...

Comment: @Darkie When I did configured my Glass, I forgot to registrer them in the android_winusb.inf, as it was not that much documented. Sorry to ask, but have you done that? I must say that appart from that, I can't see any possible direction... Maybe re-installing the driver with the ones held in Android SDK folder would help. PS: sorry for the typos everywhere :/

Comment: @Rems I have also done that . uninstalling and then re-install also done I have tried every solution on this site and others but didn't help me that. and it's been 5 days now and I am kind of frustrated now ... :(

Comment: @Darkie I guess so.
Can you at least access the shell of the Glass? Try `adb shell` and navigate into folders, to see if you can explore its content.

Comment: @Darkie I'll have to leave, but if you can access the shell of the Glass, you will be able to install apk's on it, and thus begin testing your app. You'll have to install through command line though, which I admit is pretty lame :/
But it's just to start, while you haven't figured out why DDMS does not display your device

Comment: @Darkie and try using `monitor` through command line instead of DDMS through Android Studio; you never know. Good luck with that, keep me aware!

Comment: @Rems ok then I will try to do it by shell and I think that the only way I have got now ... :)
And Yeah I will keep you updated but now I also have to leave the office until then wish me luck .. :)

Comment: @Rems I tried it using shell commands and neither that worked out. I think there might be a problem with the glass. what do you say ?