# Google glass sample projects are crashing

Tags: java, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

So I am attempting to learn to develop for Glass and was going through the quickstart guide today. Attempted to run all of the sample apps and they all crashed upon me attempting to open them. With a picture of caution sign saying "Stopwatch has stopped tap to continue". I tried reimporting the projects restarting glass and nothing worked. Any ideas? Also my glass initally wasnt recognized by eclipse and followed this guide [Google Glass ADB devices doesn't find. OMAP4430 driver not installed (can't find it!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928983/google-glass-adb-devices-doesnt-find-omap4430-driver-not-installed-cant-find) to get it recognized. Not sure if that has anything to do with it but figured I should let you all know.

here is the logcat for the stopwatch crash

```
    12-21 16:59:46.109: D/AndroidRuntime(1308): Shutting down VM
12-21 16:59:46.109: W/dalvikvm(1308): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40db71f8)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.glass.timeline.TimelineManager.createLiveCard
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at com.google.android.glass.sample.stopwatch.StopwatchService.onStartCommand(StopwatchService.java:57)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2359)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:123)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
12-21 16:59:46.109: E/AndroidRuntime(1308):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you're compiling against the XE11 version of the GDK but running on a device with XE12. Make sure that you've updated your GDK add-on to the latest version using the Android SDK Manager.