# NoSuchMethod Exception for createLiveCard

Tags: adt, google-glass, google-gdk

I am learning how to use the GDK and a nice explorer shared their HelloWorld project with me (https://code.google.com/p/hello-world-google-glass/source/checkout)

Unfortunately when I try to run the code I get the error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   com.google.android.glass.timeline.TimelineManager.createLiveCard

I have been searching for solutions, but the closest I could find to my problem was addressed in this post: [Google glass sample projects are crashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20724049/google-glass-sample-projects-are-crashing)

As the accepted answer suggested, I went into the SDK manager and updated my whole API 15, including the GDK sneak peak.  My GDK shows Revision 2.  Still doesn't work.

Even weirder, all of the sample apps Google included work just fine.  Any advice?

EDIT: The sample apps DO NOT WORK just fine, I just realized when I manually launch the apps instead of voice command, I am actually given 2 choices of each app.  One works, one gives the exact same error as described above.  I imagine the working one came from MyGlass and the other is the one I loaded.

EDIT #2 I looked on MyGlass and it turns out my Glass is running XE11 instead of 12.  I can't find any instructions on how to update it to XE12.  Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GDK incompatible changes were introduced in the change between XE11 and XE12, so this makes some sense.

It is a little odd that you're on XE11 still, however. There is no way to force the upgrade, but it should happen on its own when charging and on WiFi. You may want to do a reset (hold the power button down for 15 seconds - this is just a forced power off instead of sleep and won't delete anything) and see if that resolves anything or a hard reset (which **will** delete everything) from the settings menu. You may also want to contact a Glass Guide for further assistance in getting the upgrade.

Comment: I am using Glass at my university, and the Wi-Fi here is locked up pretty tight.  I have been internet browsing using the bluetooth tether to my phone's 4G.  Does it need to be connected to Wi-Fi directly in order to update? Does the 4G connection not work?

Comment: It may not to avoid data overages. Contact a Glass Guide to see if there is another way.

Comment: I went to a friend's apartment and connected to his Wi-Fi and lo and behold, Glass updated.  All of my glassware works now.  Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

To connect to secured Wifi, you can try Connectify (http:www.connectify.me) and turn your laptop into a Hotspot. First, connect the laptop to school wifi with authentication, then share the hotspot with your Glass. I assume that you know how to generate QR Code for Google Glass to connect to Wifi. The info is available on glass.google.com/myglass

Once it connects via Wifi, it should be able to upgrade. If Glass does not prompt you to upgrade to XE12 after connecting to Wifi, you can try Prisoner's suggestion to reset the Glass. BTW, thanks for trying my Hello World app. Good Luck!

Comment: That's a great tip, unfortunately I'm running Ubuntu and it doesn't seem connectify has a Linux version. I'm currently looking to see if there is a substitute.  Thanks again for the HelloWorld app, it really helped me a lot =]

Comment: I think the easiest way is to modify the code and reverse the LiveCard (in GService) back to XE11 version without PublishMode. See the sample that shows the minor differences - https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-timer-sample/commit/ae1dbfd5f4db5a79e283820aab95846122842085#diff-c441028ebc6c6127c94241c9e518338c