# Google Glass 2.0 not getting Detected by Adb, any Solutions?

Tags: debugging, windows-8, adb, google-glass

I recently got Google Glass 2.0 and the pc(Windows 8) detects the device but the adb does not recognize it, is there any solutions for this?
And I tried the solution in this link and it did not work [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390624/ddms-unable-to-see-google-glass)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hardware ids might be different from the answer you followed. See [this other stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17138336/77914) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Buddy It worked...! I changed the Hardware Id and it worked...!