# Connectivity problems with Glass

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've created a small Glass app and am trying to help someone else side load the .apk file directly on on their Glass as part of internal testing.  I had them install the Eclipse + ADT Bundle, run the SDK Manager, etc (i.e. the basic instructions from [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/quick-start)).  They verified that the Google USB driver does show up in the SDK Manager.

With the device plugged in, running "adb wait-for-device" hangs.  So it doesn't appear device communication is working.  The device also does not show up in DDMS in Eclipse.

They verified that USB debugging is enabled on the Glass itself under settings.

I also tried having them follow the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20390624/ddms-unable-to-see-google-glass/20412429#20412429) but this also did not help.  They are able to see the Glass removable storage device in windows.

Any suggestions on what else to try?  I do recall that with my Glass device at one point I put it on and it asked me if I wanted to allow debugging from the computer where it was plugged in.  I'm not sure if this could be a roadblock here or not but I'm also not sure how to get to that prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get the correct values into android_winusb.inf it works fine, see
[Google Glass ADB devices doesn't find. OMAP4430 driver not installed (can't find it!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928983/google-glass-adb-devices-doesnt-find-omap4430-driver-not-installed-cant-find)

Here's an example on a Win7 box:
[image: screen capture with hardware IDs, android_winusb.inf and adb output]

(edited to include screen capture)

Comment: That link appears to have the same info as the link I included in the original post.

Comment: What are the string values in: the ;Google Glass sections of andtoid_winusb.inf and in the Hardware Ids properties of the Android ADB Interface as seen in the Device Manager?

Comment: on my machine (which is working) I have only 1 entry in device mgr, "Android Composite ADB Interface" which has the following two hardware IDs: USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&REV_0216&MI_01 and USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01.  The .inf entries are taken from the link I posted in my original question above.  Interestingly it works but my .inf doesn't have an entry with this exact combo (REV_0216 and MI_01).  I don't understand the format though - are those all expected to match?  are they optional?  Do you?  Waiting to get info back on the machine with the problem.

Comment: That did it!  I think this is the key.  Figure out the hardware Ids and then make sure your android_winusb.inf file contains those.  Doing this got it up and running on the other environment.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest workaround is to find a Mac, Chromebook or Linux computer.  Windows with ADB and Glass is nothing but pain.

Comment: well, thanks but I'm hoping someone has a trick to getting it going on Windows :)

Comment: I wonder if Linux running inside VirtualBox would be able to communicate well with Glass over USB plugged into the host operating system?  Still a bit of a hack-around compared to just having it work IN windows :)