# Computer not finding Google Glass fastboot driver

Tags: android, adb, google-glass, fastboot

I'm trying to use the fastboot mode on my Google Glass device in order to root the device.  However, when I start fastboot mode using `adb reboot bootloader` from the command prompt, my computer can't find the driver, so I can't send fastboot commands from my command prompt.

I've tried modeling my solution in the same way as the previous post [Google Glass ADB devices doesn't find. OMAP4430 driver not installed (can't find it!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928983/google-glass-adb-devices-doesnt-find-omap4430-driver-not-installed-cant-find), but it hasn't worked.

I currently have these lines under both the [Google.NTx86] section and the [Google.NTamd64] section in my android_winusb file in the usb_driver folder in my sdk:

```
;Google Glass
%SingleBootLoaderInterface% = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%SingleAdbInterface%        = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001
%CompositeAdbInterface%     = USB_Install, USB\VID_18D1&PID_9001&MI_01
```

I've tried using the device manager and manually directing the Glass device to the usb_driver folder in my sdk to update the driver software, but it's not working.

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: try this http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found instructions to create a universal adb driver here: http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-make-truly-universal-adb-and.html

I modified my android_winusb.inf file as per the instructions on this blog, and after that I was able to update my driver software using the device manager.  I directed the device manager to the usb_driver folder in my sdk for the update, as I was doing before.

Thanks to Alex P. for the suggestion on checking out the blog page